# Python module resolution

Tags: python, command-line, pip

I have a question about the command **python -m pip install ...**
Reading the documentation, it shows that the -m flag/option is used to identify a python module, the moudle is resolved by searching in the sys.path entries. In the above command, are we essentially asking the interpreter to search for pip in the sys.path? I located pip and it seems to be an executable and not a module, so does the -m flag also work for executables? Provided their locations are listed in the system path entries?

[image]

i searched for the pip file and found that its an executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are both. The is a `pip` module, somewhere like `.../site-packages/pip`, and the top-level executable script. The `-m` does run a module as a main script, but it can also run a package as main script if it has a special file name `__main__.py` in it. The `pip` package has this. So the package can be run as if it were the main script. Python will run what is in that `__main__.py` file.

This is a good way to target a specific pip for a specific version of Python, if you have more than one version of Python installed on your system.